# Integrate Jenkins with sonarqube Community Edition to scan mulesoft based project

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, mule, jenkins-plugins

If we integrate jenkins with sonarqube community edition, are we able to configure a job to scan a mulesoft based project and not just default java/maven, etc?
If so is there any additional configuration needed, or is the sonarqube scanner able to pick the mule project by default and able to scan all its code?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the XML plugin into Sonar, then run a maven build like this:

```
mvn -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarhost -Dsonar.sources=src/main/mule org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
```

Note the sonar.sources property pointing to the location of the Mule xml configuration files.

This will get the XML files to show up in Sonarqube, but test coverage analysis doesn't work. You should upvote this 'idea' in the Mulesoft support portal: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#087340000005nkVAAQ